# Is there a way to simulate an arbitrary number of random biased coin flips

Tags: probability, functions

I'm a programmer, not a mathematician so please excuse my pseudo maths. If there are any glaring mistakes I will be more than happy to learn and fix them.

The problem that I'm having is programming in origin. If I have $n$ number of coins to flip the time it takes to simulate each flip approaches infinity as $n$ approaches infinity. Is there a function that is between $1 \geq x \geq 0$ where $x$ approaches $1$, $y$ approaches the max number of flips to turn tails. I suspect this function would mostly remain unchanged in the center as $n$ increases as having more or less than half for large numbers becomes increasingly unlikely. It would be amazing if this function can also allow bias.

I have found the inverse error function and I transformed it to fit between $0$ and $1$ however as $x$ approaches $1$ or $0$ it becomes infinity or negative infinity respectfully, which means there is a chance that more than all the coins could be flipped to tails which tipped me off that I'm probably using the wrong function.

Comment: What does "the max number of flips to turn tails", "this function would mostly remain unchanged in the center as  increases as having more or less than half for large numbers becomes increasingly unlikely. It would be amazing if this function can also allow bias" mean?

Comment: If you don't allow for an arbitrarily large number of flips to be heads in a row then it's not random.

Comment: The way I usually to it is to uniformly pick a number between $0$ and $1$ and return heads if the number is less than my $p$. Also, every biased coin should allow for the possibility all the flips are tails, except the coin that always gives heads, unless you are using a different kind of "biased coin".

Comment: @DonThousand The maximum number of coins that will flip tails is equal to $n$ because one can't flip coins and get more than $n$ coins tails up. The slope in the middle will remain low because with large amounts of coins around half the coins will be the most common result unless I'm thinking about this wrong. With the final one if the coins were unfair ie 80% chance of heads and 20% chance of tails then more will flip heads. If the function assumed it would be fair then I would expect that it will most often spit out half heads instead of an 80%-20% mix

Comment: @CyclotomicField Yes in this case I would like it if 1 is all the coins and 0 is none flipped up heads or tails. To be clear (mostly for myself) if I use this function to flip 100 coins 0 would result in 100 heads and 1 will result in 100 tails swapping heads or tails if you want because that doesn't matter.

Comment: You should edit your question to incorporate your comments, and to otherwise clarify what kind of function you want.  Ideally, it should include graphs of the desired function.

Comment: @DoshorteDovencio  Is this relevant to what you're asking?  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1427288/how-to-sample-a-binomial-random-variable