# Instantaneous simulation of identical probability trials over time

Tags: probability

I'm making a Minecraft mod and I've run into a math problem.

#### Edit:

Upon further investigation and helpful comments, I've discovered that this is just sequential independent burnoulli trials. I'm trying to solve for $k$, given $p$, $n$, and $P(k)$.

### Background:

In-game, crop growth occurs through random chance every tick (1 tick = 1/20 seconds). Every tick, the crop has a chance to get updated. Every update, the crop has a chance to grow 1 stage. I want to calculate how much a plant would have grown, if it had been receiving these update ticks over a finite period of time.

### Problem:

- Every tick a crop has a $u$ chance to be updated
- Every successful update, a crop has an $g$ chance to grow 1 state

How many states will a given plant grow over $t$ ticks?

I know it's a random value, I'm trying to simulate the randomness of running the calculations in real time with a single calculation.

### My current solution:

I've been doing this sequentially, i.e.

```
for (int tick = 0; tick < t; tick++) {
   if (Math.random() < u) {
      if (Math.random() < g) {
         plant.growth += 1;
      }
   }
}
```

But that's really ugly and not mathematical at all. I know there must be a mathematical way to calculate the growth all at once, but I can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated :)

### Notes:

This is different from normal consecutive independent probability problems. I'm not asking "what is the probability of growing 5 stages in 500 ticks?" Instead, I'm asking "how many stages will the crop grow in 500 ticks?" That's why I can't find anything on google or in textbooks, because it's a strange question.

Comment: We don’t know how many stages the crop will grow - because it’s random! But we do know that on average the growth will be $u \times g$ stages, if I understand your explanation correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I know what you mean, my language was off. To clarify, I meant can I calculate an accurate random number representing what would have happened if I had run these numbers in real time :)

Comment: Each of your ticks is a Bernoulli trial with probability $u\cdot g$, so the growth stages follow a Binomial distribution with parameters $(num_ticks, u\cdot g)$. One method of drawing samples can be found at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1427288/how-to-sample-a-binomial-random-variable